# DB connection in java--Query in JSP--Is it possible? And how

Tags: java, postgresql, jsp

so here is my thought and problem at the same time...

I will create eventually a **web app with Netbeans.**

I have started by creating the database in **POSTGRESQL** which is ready and filled. 
Anyway, to the point, of my first problem:

I have created a **Java class**, which manages to create a connection with the database. The method i am using, produces a Connection variable and returns it.

I don't want to make the query in there, BUT in the **Jsp page**. Is it possible? ALL the examples i have seen, are making the SQL Query in the Java page and not in the JSP page. But i don't want this, cause the queries i will make in the future of my project, will be like...thousands!

In general,i want the Db connection in the Java file and the Queries in jsp files.

What do you think?

thanks

Comment: Pass your query from JSP to Java class as parameter.

Comment: It is possible, with the [standard SQL tag library](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnald.html) ([tutorials](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_database_access.htm)), but it's highly against the usual MVC separation.

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure your question is violating the rules. Whatever.

Did you try NamedQueries? It's some time ago since I last wrote Java or JSP Code but as I understood your question, this should solve your problem.

Here a [link](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/named)

Explanation:

> A named query is a statically defined query with a predefined
>   unchangeable query string. Using named queries instead of dynamic
>   queries may improve code organization by separating the JPQL query
>   strings from the Java code. It also enforces the use of query
>   parameters rather than embedding literals dynamically into the query
>   string and results in more efficient queries.

Example:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="Country.findAll",
                query="SELECT c FROM Country c"),
    @NamedQuery(name="Country.findByName",
                query="SELECT c FROM Country c WHERE c.name = :name"),
}) 
public class Country {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry if i did anything that violates the rules, i am pretty new in StackOverflow and trying to understand a bunch of things. so if you have the time to explain to me what is that i did and violated the rules, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend you to read the explanation site. You can access it through your profile or just by this link http://stackoverflow.com/tour . "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do."

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was useful indeed. i appreciate it